# Issue with Disjunction in DetachedCriteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I'll be getting three Lists and 2 operators op1 , op2 which can  be "OR" , "AND", "AND NOT"..  i need to form a query like this

for example consider a table employee , i'll be getting three lists List1 , list2 , list3 of emp_id's

```
select emp_num , emp_dpt , emp_name

from employee

where
    emp_id in (list1)

    op1

    emp_id in (list2)

    op2

    emp_id in (list3)
```

I have written two methods

```
public List<Employee> getRequestedEmployee(List<Long> list1 , List<Long> list2, List<Long> list3 , String op1 , String op2) {

    DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Employee)

    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list1))
    {
        dc.add(Restrictions.in(list1,emp_id));
    }

    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list3)
    {
        dc = getCriteria(dc , list2 , op1);
    }

    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list3)
    {
        dc = getCriteria(dc , list3 , op2);
    }
}

private DetachedCriteria getCriteria( DetachedCriteria dc , List<long> empIdList, String operator)
{
    if(!CollectionUtils.IsEmpty(empIdList))
    {
        if("and".equals(operator))
        {
            Conjunction andOp = Restrictions.Conjunction();
            andOp.add(Restrictions.in(empIdList));
            dc.add(andOp);
        }
        else if("or".equals(operator))
        {
            Disjunction orOp = restrictions.disjunction();
            orOp.add(Restrictions.in(empIdList))
            dc.add(andOp);
        }
        else
        {
             dc.add(Restrictions.not(empIdList));
        }
        return dc;
    }
}
```

I am facing problem with Disjunction .. When ever am passing OR it is interpreting as AND..

for example if am passing `op1 = and`, `op2 = or` it is forming like this

```
select emp_num , emp_dpt , emp_name

from employee

where
    emp_id in (list1)

    and

    emp_id in (list2)

    and

    emp_id in (list3)
```

but what i want is

```
select emp_num , emp_dpt , emp_name

from employee

where
    emp_id in (list1)

    and

    emp_id in (list2)

    or

    emp_id in (list3)
```

where ever am expecting or it is putting and no matter op1 or op2

Need some help...

Answer (score 0):

the `And` comes from `dc.add()`. Every add will be one criteria which is put together with and. a disjunction with 1 argument is basicly a noop because `crit and <nothing>` = `crit`. You need to accumulate the criterions on criterion level not on query/criteria level

```
public List<Employee> getRequestedEmployee(List<Long> list1 , List<Long> list2, List<Long> list3 , String op1 , String op2)
{
    ICriterion crit = null;

    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list1))
    {
        crit = Restrictions.in("emp_id", list1));
    }

    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list3)
    {
        crit = addCriteria(crit , list2 , op1);
    }

    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list3)
    {
        crit = addCriteria(crit , list3 , op2);
    }

    DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Employee);
    if (crit != null)
    {
        query = query.add(crit);
    }
    return query;
}

private ICriterion addCriteria( ICriterion existingCrit, List<long> empIdList, String operator)
{
    if(CollectionUtils.IsEmpty(empIdList))
    {
        return existingCrit;
    }

    ICriterion crit = Restrictions.in("emp_Id", empIdList);

    if(existingCrit == null)
    {
        return crit;
    }
    else if("and".equals(operator))
    {
        return Restrictions.conjunction()
            .add(existingCrit);
            .add(crit);
    }
    else if("or".equals(operator))
    {
        return Restrictions.disjunction()
            .add(existingCrit);
            .add(crit);
    }
    else // "not"
    {
        return Restrictions.conjunction()
            .add(existingCrit);
            .add(Restrictions.not(crit));
    }
}
```